# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/time/FastDateFormat

Tags: java, spring, исключения

У меня по условию есть параметр который подается на вход хранимой процедуре.
в Т/З записан как.
declare @date_now  datetime

в конструкторе который отправляется в ХП я просто передаю new Date()

соответственно, после обработки

```
Map<String, Object> inParams = new HashMap();
inParams.put("@date_now", date_now);
Map<String, Object> outParams = execute(inParams);
```

падает ошибка
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/time/FastDateFormat

и следом.

```
19:04:54,300 ERROR [org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler] (taskScheduler-1) Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/time/FastDateFormat
    at ru.liberty.kladr.yandex.db.LoggedStoredProcedure.format(LoggedStoredProcedure.java:179) [classes:]
    at ru.liberty.kladr.yandex.db.LoggedStoredProcedure.formatDateValue(LoggedStoredProcedure.java:167) [classes:]
    at ru.liberty.kladr.yandex.db.LoggedStoredProcedure.logInputParameters(LoggedStoredProcedure.java:135) [classes:]
    at ru.liberty.kladr.yandex.db.LoggedStoredProcedure.execute(LoggedStoredProcedure.java:57) [classes:]
    at ru.liberty.kladr.scheduler.db.WsAddressSave.getInfo(WsAddressSave.java:64) [classes:]
    at ru.liberty.kladr.scheduler.db.DadataRepository.getWsAddressSaveInfo(DadataRepository.java:60) [classes:]
    at ru.liberty.kladr.scheduler.service.QueueDadataTask.getObjectWsAddressGetFromQueue(QueueDadataTask.java:114) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65) [spring-context-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset$$$capture(FutureTask.java:308) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.time.FastDateFormat from [Module "deployment.location-service.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Ошибка означает, что в CLASSPATH нет jar-файла зависимости Apache Commons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В CLASSPATH или зависимости проекта необходимо добавить библиотеку [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/). Судя по Exception у вас должна быть вторая версия. См. [версия 2.6](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi)